# Reusable identifier cells versus returning a cell subclass?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

I create my table view cells in xib files that I then register with my table view and return in `cellForRowAt` using the `tableView.dequeueReusableCell` method. In the rare instance I create cells by subclassing them and manually programming the interface I usually just initialise them and return them from within `cellForRowAt`.

I recently discovered that you can register subclasses using `tableView.register(cellClass: AnyClass?, forCellReuseIdentifier: String)`. Should I be registering my subclasses and returning them via `dequeueReusableCell`? What are the benefits of using it instead of returning an initialised subclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to always register cell(via code or in storyboard). The Reusability principle is the most important in iOS Table and Collection views.
It means that the table view draws and stores in the memory only few cells that are currently visible + several that mat be visible in the nearest future. If you will not use reusability you will have a big performance problems with big amount of cells.

Also don't forget to clean cells ui in prepareForReuse method in cell subclasses

Comment: Wasn’t aware of the `prepareForReuse` method, thanks for mentioning it

Comment: You should. In case of labels that can be filled in cellFor or willDisplay immediately you will not see the difference. But once you try to do it with asynchronic data(like image loading) you may see how the old images are reused and become updated in a few second. I recommend you to try it just to know how it shouldn't work)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be taking advantage of the cell reuse system.  The reuse system allows the system to very rapidly respond to scroll actions on your table.  Instead of having to instantiate a whole new cell from scratch the system can just take cells it already has and update their content.

Bypassing that system by making a whole new cell every time is not an ideal use of resources and with more complex cells can result in noticeable lag on your table view.